# calculate total of string column

Tags: python, pandas

How do I calculate total of string columns in pandas?

```
myl=[('2012-11-07 19:16:07', ' 2012-11-07 19:21:07', ' 0h 05m 00s'),
 ('2012-11-13 06:16:07', ' 2012-11-13 06:21:07', ' 0h 05m 00s'),
 ('2012-11-15 09:56:07', ' 2012-11-15 11:41:07', ' 1h 45m 00s'),
 ('2012-11-15 22:26:07', ' 2012-11-16 07:01:07', ' 8h 35m 00s')]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(myl, columns=['from', 'to', 'downtime'])
```

The above code will return the "downtime" in a single column. How do I take the total of integer values in that column?

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                  from                    to     downtime
0  2012-11-07 19:16:07   2012-11-07 19:21:07   0h 05m 00s
1  2012-11-13 06:16:07   2012-11-13 06:21:07   0h 05m 00s
2  2012-11-15 09:56:07   2012-11-15 11:41:07   1h 45m 00s
3  2012-11-15 22:26:07   2012-11-16 07:01:07   8h 35m 00s
```

For e.g. in the above output, expected total of downtime column would be 9h 90m 00s

---

Update:

And how do I calculate day-wise downtime?

Expected result:

```
2012-11-07 0h 05m 00s
2012-11-13 0h 05m 00s
2012-11-15 10h 20m 00s
```

This is working as expected:

```
df['downtime_t'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['downtime'])

df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['from'])).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['from'])).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['from'])).day

df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day'])['downtime_t'].sum()
```

And this is also working for year grouping:

```
df['from_d2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from'])
df.groupby(df['from_d2'].map(lambda x:  x.year ))['downtime_t'].sum()
```

But this does not work:

```
df.groupby(df['from_d2'].map(lambda x:  x.year, x.month, x.day))['downtime_t'].sum()
```

Is there any other way to achieve group by total?

Comment: Do you want exactly that result, or is `10h 30m 00s` also good? (or better?)

Comment: 10h 30m 00s is better and correct !

Comment: You should convert first the date column to `datetimes`, and the downtime columns to timedeltas, then you can just do `df.groupby(df['from'].dt.date()).mean()`

Comment: Sorry, I is ``df['from'].dt.date`` without the parantheses (property and not a method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' `to_timedelta` function.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['downtime']).sum()
```

Comment: getting an error # ValueError: cannot create timedelta string converter for [0h 05m 00s] # pandas version is '0.14.1'

Comment: There were a lot of enhancements in the timedelta handling (with the introduction of Timedelta scalar and TimedeltaIndex) in 0.15. Possibly you will have to update.

Comment: Yes. It worked with the version 0.15  Updated question.